# in svelte using getter with Object.values() "Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: javascript, stack-overflow, svelte

I am using the svelte.js framework

[image]

and I am using a function that returns an object like this `{x, y, rotated, isMoving}`

the problem is that `isMoving` use getter

```js
{
  get isMoving() {
    return Object.values(this)
  }
}
```

> basically I want all the values to be in a array and then loop on it.

---

```js
function activeAxis() {
  return {
    x: x !== prevCoords.x && y === prevCoords.y,
    y: y !== prevCoords.y && x === prevCoords.x,
    rotated: y !== prevCoords.y && x !== prevCoords.x,
    get isMoving() {
      return Object.values(this)
    }
  };
}
```

---

the array is a series of points with x and y

like this:

```js
let array = [{
    x: 10
    y: 20
  },
  {
    x: 15
    y: 20
  },
  {
    x: 25,
    y: 9
  },
  {
    x: 25,
    y: 30
  },
  {
    x: 25,
    y: 25
  },
  {
    x: 25
    y: 25
  }
]
```

Comment: `isMoving` simply returning all values makes no sense, what is the property supposed to do?

Comment: @H.B. no I need to do another thing on it with a loop. basically check if all values are false, then do isMoving true, if one of the values is true then isMoving became false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> like he said to you **@konrad**, if you can try to not use `this`
>
>  and I saw that you answered **@H.B.** with the purpose of the getter function.

so with these details, I think that

the best way is to refactor your code

and not use `this` and also not a `for` loop because isn't necessary

```js
function activeAxis() {
  const sameX = x === prevCoords.x;
  const sameY = y === prevCoords.y;

  return {
    x: sameY && !sameX,
    y: sameX && !sameY,
    rotated: !sameX && !sameY,
    sameCoord: sameX && sameY
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. It's not related to svelte
2. By calling `Object.values(this)` in a getter you are calling this getter in a loop and never return an actual value.
3. Just don't do this

Better use one of these:

```js
function activeAxis() {
  return {
    x: x !== prevCoords.x && y === prevCoords.y,
    y: y !== prevCoords.y && x === prevCoords.x,
    rotated: y !== prevCoords.y && x !== prevCoords.x,
  };
}

console.log(Object.values(activeAxis())
```

```js
function activeAxis() {
  return {
    x: x !== prevCoords.x && y === prevCoords.y,
    y: y !== prevCoords.y && x === prevCoords.x,
    rotated: y !== prevCoords.y && x !== prevCoords.x,
    isMoving() {
      return Object.values(this)
    }
  };
}

console.log(activeAxis().isMoving())
```

Comment: and how can I get the same Object? without using `this`? and get that error. thanks

Comment: `Object.values(activeAxis())`

Comment: is seems like recursive, it's keep rerendering, and in a some point it tell me "[HMR][Svelte] Failed to rerender <Gline>"

Comment: Did you remove that getter before running that??

Comment: I'm done sorry :/

Comment: I found the solution, thanks the same